# use cursor as iterator with a query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I was reading about mongodb. Came across this part http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial It says -

```
> var cursor = db.things.find();
> printjson(cursor[4]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c220a42f3924d31102bd858"), "x" : 4, "j" : 3 }
```

"When using a cursor this way, note that all values up to the highest accessed (cursor[4] above) are loaded into RAM at the same time. This is inappropriate for large result sets, as you will run out of memory. Cursors should be used as an iterator with any query which returns a large number of elements."

How to use cursor as iterator with a query?Thanks for the help

Answer (score 15):

You've tagged that you're using pymongo, so I'll give you two pymongo examples using the cursor as an iterator:

```py
import pymongo
cursor = pymongo.Connection().test_db.test_collection.find()
for item in cursor:
    print item
    #this will print the item as a dictionary
```

and

```py
import pymongo
cursor = pymongo.Connection().test_db.test_collection.find()
results = [item['some_attribute'] for item in cursor]
#this will create a list comprehension containing the value of some_attribute
#for each item in the collection
```

In addition, you can set the size of batches returned to the pymongo driver by doing this:

```py
import pymongo
cursor = pymongo.Connection().test_db.test_collection.find()
cursor.batchsize(20) #sets the size of batches of items the cursor will return to 20
```

It is usually unnecessary to mess with the batch size, but if the machine you are running the driver on is having memory issues and page faulting while you are manipulating results from the query, you might have to set this to achieve better performance (this really seems like a painful optimization to me and I've always left the default).

As far as the javascript driver (the driver that loads when you launch the "shell") that part of the documentation is cautioning you not to use "array mode". From the online manual:

> Array Mode in the Shell
>
> Note that in some languages, like JavaScript, the driver supports an
>   "array mode". Please check your driver documentation for specifics.
>
> In the db shell, to use the cursor in array mode, use array index []
>   operations and the length property.
>
> Array mode will load all data into RAM up to the highest index
>   requested. Thus it should not be used for any query which can return
>   very large amounts of data: you will run out of memory on the client.
>
> You may also call toArray() on a cursor. toArray() will load all
>   objects queries into RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Using the MongoDB Java driver it should be something like:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find( query );
while( cursor.hasNext() ) {
     DBObject obj = cursor.next();
     // do something tih obj
}
```

In the mongo console you can do something like:

```
var cursor = db.things.find();
while(cursor.hasNext()) { printjson(cursor.next()); }
```

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB` returns results in batches. To see how many objects are left in a batch, we use `objLeftInBatch()` like this:

```
var c = db.Schools.find();
var doc = function() {return c.hasNext()? c.next : null;}
c.objLeftInBatch();
```

To iterate through this batch we can use `doc()` that we setup in the above code block. More learning on cursors can be found at https://docs.mongodb.com/